# C++ header and .cc file issue with class member

Tags: c++, header-files

I am receiving the error below by implementing my Vertex class in MyFile.h and MyFile.cc

```
// MyFile.h
#ifndef FILE
#define FILE

#include <set> 

class Vertex{                                                   
public:
    int i, j; 
    set<Vertex*> adj; //references to adjacent vertices (max of 4)

    Vertex();
    ~Vertex();
    //end constructors

    void setPos(int row, int col);

    /** must overload for set<Vertex> to function */
    const bool operator < (const Vertex &o) const;

};//END class Vertex

#endif


// MyFile.cc
#include "MyFile.h"
#include <set>
using namespace std;


Vertex::Vertex():i(-1), j(-1), adj(0,5)/*may store [0,4] elements*/{}

Vertex::~Vertex(){
    adj.clear();
}
//end constructors

void Vertex::setPos(int row, int col){
    i = row;
    j = col;
}//end setPos()

/** must overload for set<Vertex> to function */
const bool Vertex::operator < (const Vertex &o) const{
    if(i < o.i) 
        return true;
    if(i > o.i)
        return false;
    return j < o.j; 
}


/** connect v1 and v2 such that they are adjacent */
void addEdge(Vertex* v1, Vertex* v2){
    v1->adj.insert(v2);
    v2->adj.insert(v1);
}//end addEdge
```

I've tried several ways to implement the class but I keep receiving this error:

```
In file included from MyFile.cc:5:0:
MyFile.h:15:2: error: 'set' does not name a type
  set<Vertex*> adj; //references to adjacent vertices (max of 4)
  ^
MyFile.cc: In constructor 'Vertex::Vertex()':
MyFile.cc:15:32: error: class 'Vertex' does not have any field named 'ad
j'
 Vertex::Vertex():i(-1), j(-1), adj(0,5)/*may store [0,4] elements*/{}
                                ^
MyFile.cc: In destructor 'Vertex::~Vertex()':
MyFile.cc:18:2: error: 'adj' was not declared in this scope
  adj.clear();
  ^
MyFile.cc: In function 'void addEdge(Vertex*, Vertex*)':
MyFile.cc:39:6: error: 'class Vertex' has no member named 'adj'
  v1->adj.insert(v2);
      ^
MyFile.cc:40:6: error: 'class Vertex' has no member named 'adj'
  v2->adj.insert(v1);
      ^
make: *** [MyFile.o] Error 1
```

Perhaps there's something I'm missing because I'm still learning how to efficiently use header files.  Could anyone give me any suggestions?

Comment: In your class definition, `std::set<Vertex*> adj;`. And use something other than `FILE` for the include guard - that's a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 2):

You declare a field

```
set<Vertex*> adj;
```

but you construct it with

```
adj(0,5);
```

You cannot expect the `5` to be converted to a pointer to `Vertex`

I would suggest to use some [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer), perhaps a [shared_ptr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/)

```
std::set<std::shared_ptr<Vertex>> adj;
```

assuming [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) code.

Please read more about [C++ programming](http://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html). Also read the [documentation of `std::set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) (notice that the ["range constructor"](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/set/) wants *iterators* into some already existing set)

I would construct `adj` as an empty set and fill it later (at least inside the constructor of `Vertex`)

Comment: I believe Set has a constructor determining how many elements it may contain.  I've tried this also such as allocating memory with an empty constructor and it still says Vertex has no field name "adj"

Comment: Instead of "believing" (in C++ programming most beliefs are wrong) you should read the [documentation of `std::set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/)

Comment: The reason I chose to "believe" was because it was what I interpreted from "(2) range constructor
Constructs a container with as many elements as the range [first,last), with each element constructed from its corresponding element in that range."  But I could have misinterpreted it.

Answer (score 0):

The following error message gives a good clue:

```
In file included from MyFile.cc:5:0:
MyFile.h:15:2: error: 'set' does not name a type
  set<Vertex*> adj; //references to adjacent vertices (max of 4)
```

You need to use:

```
  std::set<Vertex*> adj;
```

But then, the comment in the following line of code does not make sense:

```
Vertex::Vertex():i(-1), j(-1), adj(0,5)/*may store [0,4] elements*/{}
```

`std::set` does not have a constructor that will do what you are hoping to.

Comment: Even though I'm using "using namespace std;" in MyFile.cc?  Can you explain why?

Comment: `using namespace std;` is after the `#include "File.h"` line. When the compiler parses the code, the contents of `File.h` are seen before `using namespace std;`.